# Word 2016 Letterhead Template

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, templates, microsoft-word-2016

I have a letterhead template and I need the first page left margin to be smaller than subsequent pages.

Is there a way to do this? Even willing to use VBA to get it accomplished.  I need first page margins to be: Left: 0.5 Top: 1" Right: 1" Bottom: 1".  Then on page 2, and every page after to be 1" as normal.

The issue with using a section break is the following:
Next Page Section Break. (will move while the user is typing)
Continuous Section Break. (will not allow separate margins.)

This is trying to be made with the mindset that user can open template and type letter, and if the letter extends to a 2nd page it would have normal margins of 1" all around, but the 1st page will have different margins to fit Letterhead info in Left Margin and Logo in top header.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: You can do this by inserting a section break and then setting the margins for the section before the break and then another set of margins after the break.

Comment: " I just need my first page margins to be left -.15 and the rest 1 all around. Then on page 2 and so on be 1" as normal. " that makes the first page margin **smaller** than the rest of the document. Please clarify by [edit]ing the question.

Comment: BillDOe, I appreciate the suggestion but that will not work for the purposes I need.  Which is to have a master template a user could use to write a company letter.

Comment: This article may help, though there are issues if using bullets on the first page:  http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/LetterheadRibbon.htm.

Comment: pro3carp3, thank you for the article.  Unfortunately there is no way to know if they will use bullet styles or not in their letter so if possible I would like to avoid using it.  I rather just be able to have different text margins.

I know that the only way for this to be done would somehow to tell word after it's first automatic break; to reset margins to normal.  How to code that I'm not sure.

Answer (score -1):

- Show the ruler, so you can change the left margin (View menu>Show>ruler checkbox)
- Insert a page break in the first page
- Use the ruler to change the margins (in the screen capture is shown the right margin, which you can grab and drag)

Screen capture

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjV1x.png

Comment: This will not work.  Since this is a **template** that will be filled in by the user, therefore not knowing if the letter will be 1 or 10 pages etc.